# What is making my compiler compile the code despite references to undeclared functions (in headers or otherwise)?

Tags: c

A function, before being used, needs to be declared either in a included header or otherwise (though not a good practice). The header file describes the functions and variables that may be found in a library or an object file and the compiler can create (as of yet) unreferenced symbols to be resolved later whilst linking.

However, my compiler (gcc based toolchain called [esp-open-sdk](https://github.com/pfalcon/esp-open-sdk) (xtensa CPU)) continues despite finding no reference to a function in the headers and only in the linking stage does the linker intimate of an `undefined reference to <-function-name->'.

Another strange behaviour is that the compiler says nothing if there is no return statement, and the function is not "void".

My question is: What is causing this behaviour? I think it's unlikely but is it some compiler flag?

My compiler flags are:

`CFLAGS = -Os -g -O2 -Wpointer-arith -Wundef -Werror -Wl,-EL -fno-inline-functions -nostdlib -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals  -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH`

and the linker flags are:

`LDFLAGS = -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u call_user_start -Wl,-static`

Comment: If you don't declare a function before using it, it gets a default declaration.

Comment: If you enable full warnings you should get a warning telling you when it does this.

Comment: "The header file describes the...  variables that may be found in a library" Only if poorly written by a beginner with no clue about program design.

Comment: Can you provide compilation/link result? Are you building from Arduino IDE?

Comment: @Lundin I would appreciate a bit more elaboration.

Comment: @SolomonCandy There should be no global variables exposed from a library ever. Except in some rare cases it may be ok to expose `const` qualified variables.

Comment: @Lundin Headers should be organised according to features and dependencies and not the archive structure but targeting this side-ramark for lack of elaboration is also know as "splitting hairs".

Comment: @Lundin Oh okay! Splitting hairs, as I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you use an old version of gcc. Before version 5.x, gcc defaults to a non-standard called "gnu90", which is a non-standard version of the obsolete C90 standard. There is no reason to ever use gnu90 unless you are maintaining some old Linux code. To avoid this, compile with:

```
-std=c11 -pedantic-errors
```

`-std=c11` meaning you want the compiler to use the current C standard, without involving gnus or other strange animals. `-pedantic-errors` means that you want it to actually follow the standard and not just pretend to do it.

In order to get the warning for no return from functions, you need to use the option `-Wreturn-type`, which is included by using `-Wall`. Always compile with

```
-Wall -Wextra
```

Note that "Wall" does not stand for "all warnings", as it leads you to believe. Rather, `-Wall` means a fistful of warnings and `-Wextra` means a few warnings more.